# Problema para mostrar marcadores en Google Maps

Tags: xml, google-maps

tengo un problema al leer un XML con varios datos; entre ellos la latitud y longitud de un restaurant.

La estructura del XML es:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<restaurantes>
    <restaurant>
    <imagen>1893/01.jpg</imagen>
    <nombre>1893</nombre>
    <direccion>Av. Raúl Scalabrini Ortiz 701, Villa Crespo, CABA</direccion>
    <telefono>4773-2951</telefono>
    <email>mail@1893.com</email>
    <descripcion>Descripción</descripcion>
    <latitud>-34.5971816</latitud>
    <longitud>-58.43420119999996</longitud>
    <espumante>si</espumante>
    <vino>no</vino>
    <postre>si</postre>
</restaurant>
```

Y el HTML es:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fullpage.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="css/normalize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fullpage.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'restaurantes.xml',
                dataType: 'xml',
                success: function(xml) {
                    $(xml).find('restaurant').each(function() {
                        $('#restaurantes').append(
                            '<div class="grid col-md-2 no_col-md-2">' +
                                '<figure class="effect-layla">' +           
                                    '<img src="images/restaurantes/'+ $(this).find('imagen').text() + '" alt="imagen"/>' +
                                    '<figcaption>' +
                                        '<h2>' + $(this).find('nombre').text() + '</h2>' +
                                        '<p>' + $(this).find('direccion').text() + '</p>' +
                                        '<p>' + $(this).find('telefono').text() + '</p>' +
                                        '<p><a href="#" class="ver_mas" data-toggle="modal" data-imagen="' + $(this).find('imagen').text() + '" data-nombre="' + $(this).find('nombre').text() + '"  data-direccion="' + $(this).find('direccion').text() + '" data-telefono="' + $(this).find('telefono').text() + '" data-descripcion="' + $(this).find('descripcion').text() + '" data-espumante="' + $(this).find('espumante').text() + '" data-vino="' + $(this).find('vino').text() + '" data-postre="' + $(this).find('postre').text() + '">+ VER MAS</a>' +
                                        '<p><a href="#" id="ubicar_mapa" data-longitud="' + $(this).find('longitud').text() + '" data-latitud="' + $(this).find('latitud').text() + '">UBICAR EN EL MAPA</a></p>' +
                                    '</figcaption>' +
                                '</figure>' +
                            '</div>');
                    });
                }
            });
        });   
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fullpage">
        <div class="section" id="section0">
            <video id="myVideo" loop muted data-autoplay>
                <source src="video/.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="video/.webm" type="video/webm">
            </video>
            <div class="layer">
                <div class="logo_hsbc">
                    <img style="width: 70%;" src="imagen" />
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="home_centrado">
                                <div id="logo_mundoepicureo">
                                    <img src="images/header.svg" width="70%">
                                </div>
                                <div id="logo_modomesa">
                                    <img src="images/home_modo_mesa.svg" width="85%">
                                </div>
                                <h1 class="roboto-condensed">Desconectémonos de los celulares<br><strong>para conectarnos a través de los sabores</strong></h1>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section" id="section1">
            <div class="placa_negra"></div>
            <div class="slide" id="slide1">
                <div class="container-flex">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 padding_titulo">
                            <h1>¿Qué es <strong></strong>?</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <img class="icono_chico" src="imagen" />
                            <h3><strong></strong>.</h3>
                            <div class="linea_roja">
                                <div class="container-flex">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <h3>A quienes se desconecten de sus celulares y se conecten a través de los sabores los premiamos:</h3>
                                            <img class="icono_grande" src="imagen" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section" id="section2">
            <div class="container-flex">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h2>RESTAURANTES</h2>
                        <h4>Elegí en el que te gustaría disfrutar de <strong>Modo Mesa en compañía</strong></h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row no_row" id="restaurantes"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section" id="mapa" data-percentage="80" data-centered="true" style="height: 80%;">
            <div class="container_map">
                <div id="mostrar_mapa"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section fp-auto-height" id="section4">
            <div class="container-flex">
                <h1>FOOTER</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="modal_restaurant" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                    <div id="restaurant_modal"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="principal">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4 text-left">
                                <h2 id="nombre_modal"></h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8 text-right">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-8 text-right">
                                        <h6>Este Restaurant te premia con</h6>
                                        <span id="texto_espumante_modal">ESPUMANTE + </span>
                                        <span id="texto_vino_modal">VINO + </span>
                                        <span id="texto_postre_modal">POSTRE o CAFÉ</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
                                        <div class="premio align-baseline" id="vino_modal">
                                            <img src="images/vino.png" height="50">
                                            <span>+</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="premio align-baseline" id="espumante_modal">
                                            <img src="images/espumante.png" height="50">
                                            <span>+</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="premio align-baseline" id="postre_modal">
                                            <img src="images/cafe.png" height="30">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="secundario">
                        <p id="descripcion_modal"></p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="datos">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                                <img src="images/mapa.png" width="31" height="42" class="icono_modal" />
                                <p id="direccion_modal"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                                <img src="images/celular.png" width="30" height="53" class="icono_modal" />
                                <p id="telefono_modal"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scrolloverflow.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myFullpage = new fullpage('#fullpage', {
            css3: true,
            verticalCentered: true,
            fitToSection: false,
            scrollOverflow: true,
            offsetSections: true,
            offsetSectionsKey: 'Y29kZXBlbi5pb196MDZiMlptYzJWMFUyVmpkR2x2Ym5NPWhPNA==',
            afterRender: function () {
                //Start the whole shabang when DOM and APIs are ready by calling initialize()
                initMap();
            }
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on("click", ".ver_mas", function () {
            document.getElementById("nombre_modal").innerHTML = $(this).attr('data-nombre');
            document.getElementById("descripcion_modal").innerHTML = $(this).attr('data-descripcion');
            document.getElementById("telefono_modal").innerHTML = $(this).attr('data-telefono');
            document.getElementById("direccion_modal").innerHTML = $(this).attr('data-direccion');
            imgmodal = $(this).attr('data-imagen');
            $('#restaurant_modal').css('background-image', 'url(images/restaurantes/' + imgmodal + ')');
            $('#modal_restaurant').modal('show');
            vinomodal = $(this).attr('data-vino');
            espumantemodal = $(this).attr('data-espumante');
            postremodal = $(this).attr('data-postre');

            if (vinomodal == 'no'){
                $('#vino_modal').css('display', 'none');
                $('#texto_vino_modal').css('display', 'none');
                $('#espumante_modal').css('display', 'initial');
                $('#texto_espumante_modal').css('display', 'initial');
            };

            if (espumantemodal == 'no'){
                $('#espumante_modal').css('display', 'none');
                $('#texto_espumante_modal').css('display', 'none');
                $('#vino_modal').css('display', 'initial');
                $('#texto_vino_modal').css('display', 'initial');
            };

            if (postremodal == 'no'){
                $('#postre_modal').css('display', 'none');
                $('#texto_postre_modal').css('display', 'none');
            };
        }); 
    </script>
    <script>
        var map, infoWindow;
        // Initialize and add the map
        function initMap() {
          var myOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
            zoom: 14,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            gestureHandling: 'cooperative',

            styles: [{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":36},{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":40}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":16}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":17},{"weight":1.2}]},{"featureType":"administrative.locality","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#c4c4c4"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.neighborhood","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#707070"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":21},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"poi.business","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#be2026"},{"lightness":"0"},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"},{"hue":"#ff000a"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":18}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#575757"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#2c2c2c"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":16}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#999999"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"saturation":"-52"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":19}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":17}]}]
          };

          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mostrar_mapa"), myOptions);
          infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };

            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            // infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
            // infoWindow.open(map);
            map.setCenter(pos);
          }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
          });
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }
      }

      function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                              'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                              'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
        infoWindow.open(map);
      } 
    </script>
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyByeOBo1F9jnhVnJVL-ZNbid7dIhWuxGsw&libraries=places"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'restaurantes.xml',
                dataType: 'xml',
                success: function(xml) {
                    $(xml).find('restaurant').each(function() {
                        var mapa_longitud = $(this).find('longitud').text();
                        var mapa_latitud = $(this).find('latitud').text();
                        console.log(mapa_latitud);
                        console.log(mapa_longitud);
                        lat = parseFloat( mapa_latitud );
                        lng = parseFloat( mapa_longitud );
                        var myLatLng = {lat, lng};
                        console.log(myLatLng);
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: myLatLng,
                            map: map,
                            title: 'PRUEBA'
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

Leo dos veces el XML porque no encuentro manera para que en la primera vez se lean la latitud y longitud y se cree el marcador para eso.

¿Me puede alguien dar una mano por favor?

Muchas gracias.